# Dynamically chosen nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have `Kit` model and `Product` which is related to `Kit` with foreign key. Also there are several serializers for product - `ProductASerializer` and `ProductBSerializer`.

```
class KitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductASerilaizer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Kit
        fields = ['type', 'products', ...]
```

How can I dynamically choose serializer for product, depending on type of Kit. For example If `type == 1` I use serializer A, else B. So finally It could be Kit with several serializer of which type within. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) and choosing serailizer there.

```
class KitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Kit
        fields = ['type', 'products', ...]
    def get_products(self, obj):
         if obj.type == 'A':
             return ProductASerilaizer(obj.products, many=True).data
         else:
              ....
```